# Google Sheets, how can I remove or strip specified strings

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google Sheets and trying to figure out a formula that strips or removes specific strings. So a cell might have:

`[url=https:website1]https:website1[/url] [url=https:website2]https:website2[/url]` 
and I want to convert it to
`https:website1 https:website1`

Each cell in the column will have different "websites" but the formatting will be similar. Any help is appreciated.

I've tried REGEXEXTRACT and SUBSTITUTE functions but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(ax,IF(ax="",,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(ax,"[url=",0,0),"[^\]]*"))))))
```

- 

[image]